# What is android manifest term for Android Auto?

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest

```
Android TV = leanback ,
Daydream = vrmode,
Android Wear = watch,
but Android Auto = [What]?
```

I can see first three in `<uses-feature>` of manifest but what is there for Android Auto?

Answer (score 1):

`android.hardware.type.automotive` for showing UI in the screens of a vehicle. From [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features)